# Decoding base64 to ASCII using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, decode

I've a hbase table which gets a base64 value for one of it's column. 
I'm reading the hbase table in Custom Schema with the datatypes of all columns as string.
I want to decode the same value within spark dataframe into ASCII and replace that value with the earlier encoded value of the column in the dataframe. How can this be achieved ?

dataframe value (*input*) :

```
rO0ABXQAUk9ybmF0ZSBlbWJlbGxpc2htZW50cyBwZXJmZ
WN0bHkgY29tcGxlbWVudCB0aGUgb2gtc28tY29tZm9ydGFibGUgcm9wZS1saWtlIGZvb3RiZWQ=
```

ASCII value (needed *output*) :

```
tROrnate embellishments perfectly complement the oh-so-comfortable rope-like footbed
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Java encoding & decoding apis in scala class**

```
  // Base64 encode
  val text = "tROrnate embellishments perfectly complement the oh-so-comfortable rope-like footbed"
  val bytesEncoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder.encode(text.getBytes())
  println(bytesEncoded)

  // Base64 decode
  val bytesToDecode="rO0ABXQAUk9ybmF0ZSBlbWJlbGxpc2htZW50cyBwZXJmZWN0bHkgY29tcGxlbWVudCB0aGUgb2gtc28tY29tZm9ydGFibGUgcm9wZS1saWtlIGZvb3RiZWQ="
  val textDecoded = new String(java.util.Base64.getDecoder.decode(bytesToDecode))
  println(textDecoded)
```

Comment: I want to do this operation on a column in my dataframe ? what will be the synatx for that

Comment: **Get the dataframe value in some scala variable then process on it.**                  
  `val coulmnData = spark.sql("select column2 from  MyTable").first()

val rowValue = coulmnData.get(0)`

Comment: I'm able to encode and decode my question is how to convert them into ASCII :)

Comment: @Alexandros I'm getting data into Hbase through Oracle Golden Gate directly from the source as it is. How do I encrypt the data in hbase. I can't do any manipulations with the Hbase Table. Processing should be done through scala only. Any alternative ?

Comment: Hi @PrathameshH I just saw your message. I am afraid that I dont have any alternative since I believe the issue should be fixed from the source which is the encoding in HBase.